# How to filter the first occurrence with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to filter domains from a text file which appear always at first position on each line.

File looks like:

```
Domains         Users
domain1.com     User1
domain2.com     User2
domain3.com     User3
```

Thats what I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/^[^ ]+/', $file, $matches);
```

It is producing the following result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Domains"
  }
}
```

It is taking the first line, but stops after it. Thats quite strange.

Any help here is much appreciated.

The other question I have is the following.
What is faster, the first approche with preg_match or the following.

```
$lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $file);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $line, 2);
    $domains[] = $parts[0];
}
```

Comment: Do you really need regex here? You could load up the lines into an array with `file()`, and then get your domains with substr/strpos or explode/trim ...

Comment: @One Trick Pony that's a good idea +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `m` modifier to allow multi-line mode:

```
preg_match_all('/^[^ ]+/m', $file, $matches);
                        ^-- modifiers are here
```

List of modifiers: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

> /i makes the regex match case insensitive.
>
> /s enables "single-line mode". In this mode, the dot matches newlines.
>
> /m enables "multi-line mode". In this mode, the caret and dollar match before and after
> newlines in the subject string.
>
> /x enables "free-spacing mode". In this mode, whitespace between regex tokens is ignored, and an unescaped # starts a comment.

Comment: The m modifier did it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

:D Sorry I didn't read your question to the end. :D.. I would say the explode is faster... I'm testing .... (good question! +1)

---

Update 2:

I've tested tested both, your explode attempt and the answer of @Frits van Campen and ... 'm astonished: **preg_match_all() is ~3.5 times faster**

I used a test file of 393472 lines and Ubuntu12.04 php5.3.10 and got:

*explode*

```
real    0m1.409s
user    0m1.284s
 sys    0m0.124s
```

*preg_match_all*

```
real    0m0.461s
user    0m0.384s
 sys    0m0.072s
```

So I would say @Frits van Campen's answer is best.

Comment: As you see, I'm really astonished about that. Sometimes PHP keeps a blackbox to me :).. I'll investigate **why** the `foreach` / `explode()` is much slower than `preg_match_all()` an maybe drop another update here.

Comment: That would be nice. I guess executing explode on each iteration is slowing it down. preg_match does the job on a lower level.

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: But does the speed really matter here? The point of not using regular expressions is to keep your code clean and easy to understand

Comment: @OneTrickPony I would say the regex is not too complex in this case. I would use it. But explode will also do the work, of course

Comment: Well, sometimes having a clean regex is better then having several lines of explode/trim/substr/strpos etc.